# Short unique alphanumeric ids that are protected against transcription errors

Tags: algorithms

For some payment methods users fill out paper forms with a 9-digit reference ID. Numerical IDs have the flaw that users can make transcription errors (lost digits, duplicated digits, switched digits). You can trivially detect those errors by adding a checksum (e.g. modulo-based from the ISO 7064 standard). But how can you *avoid* those errors? The only way I can think of at the moment is to make the codes shorter by encoding the numeric ID in an extended alphanumeric character set. But then you open another source of errors which is character similarity and OCR errors.

My questions are:

- Is there set of characters that's big enough to create a reduction in digits but still has low error rates in OCR/human writing? We were relatively strict and came up with `ACDEFKLMNPRTWXYZ349`.
- Does it make a difference if we create the checksum after or before encoding? The checksum itself must also be encoded, so it probably makes sense to encode after checksumming.
- Is there already a standard or a widely used implementation?

At the moment our plan is to use the following steps:

- Create a base11 checksum from numeric ID with ISO 7064 MOD 11-2.
- Convert base10 ID and base11 checksum to a base22 "number" (base22 because `ACDEFKLMNPRTWXYZ349` is 22 chars long).
- Map the two base22 "numbers" (which use `0-9` and `A-L` as digits) to our set of 22 characters.

Is there any better way?

Comment: It seems that you have many constructive ideas on what a "better way" might look like, but you have more work ahead of you in writing them down. There is some loss function you wish to optimize, which penalizes errors observed in real world, but which also penalizes codes that are "too long" or that use "too many characters". Write it down, please, formalize it. Or at least float a straw man, and then offer competing schemes. The data behind the "ACDEFKLMNPRTWXYZ349" decision would make a terrific starting point.

Comment: how does the checksum help if the user is writing the code on paper?

Comment: The checksum help to identify instances where the user has made a transcription error. If the checksum does not match, there was a transcription error and we need to do special handling.

Answer (score 1):

A potentially better way, if all users of the system share a common language (e.g. English), is to use a system similar to the one used by [what3words](https://what3words.com). The idea is to come up with a dictionary of words that can be uniquely recognized even in case of all likely misspellings.

This is, obviously, no easy task, but the fact remains that with a dictionary of at least a thousand well-chosen words, three words are enough to represent a nine-digit code, if we allow identical words to be repeated and the word order to matter.

But to minimize the risk of error, it may be best to never repeat a word and to ignore the word order. You then lose six permutations in the encoding, and you need two additional words to allow for avoiding repetition. Thus, the dictionary needs to contain 1820 words. (The cube root of six billion, plus two, rounded up.)

With four words, a dictionary size of just under 400 is sufficient.

Of course, a small set of different languages can also be supported, by offering the user a language choice when presenting the code that needs to be written. But the word lists need to be composed independently for each language. E.g. it is not a good idea to let one word list be the translation of another one, as the main goal is to have words that are unambiguous and easy to write.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! For simply avoiding transcription errors, it would be great. But the use case I outlined is having **short** codes, because users need to fill out the form by hand and the amount of characters is severely limited (~30). Also, using words instead of "IDs" could baffle users, creating a usability problem.

Comment: One thing that is often used to reduce transcription errors in e.g. license keys is grouping the "digits" into short enough groups for the short-term memory. A checksum to detect errors is still advisable, of course.